# Как запретить в EditText ввод любых символов кроме символов алфавита?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Как запретить в `EditText` ввод любых символов кроме символов алфавита? При этом алфавиты принадлежат произвольному количеству языков. Все рассматриваемые символы входят в `Unicode`.

Comment: android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужны только латинские буквы, то в xml добавьте:

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
```

Иначе

```
EditText state = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtState);

Pattern ps = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z ]+$");
Matcher ms = ps.matcher(state.getText().toString());
boolean bs = ms.matches();
if (bs == false) {
    if (ErrorMessage.contains("invalid"))
        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "state,";
    else
        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "invalid state,";
}
```

Ответ взят [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2491934/5797206)

Answer (score 2):

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start, int end, Spanned d, int dstart, int dend) { 
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
            if (!Character.isLetter(src.charAt(i))) { 
                return src.subSequence(start, i-1); 
            } 
        } 
        return null; 
    } 
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```