# Проблема с данными из поля ввода android при отправке на сервер retrofit

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

У меня есть приложение на андроид которое должно логинится на сервере для дальнейшей работы. Так вот для этого я создал интерфейс с таким кодом:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface APIService {


    Call<LoginRequest> savePost(@Field("id") Integer id, @Field("password") String password);
}
```

и у меня есть два поля для ввода куда я должен вводить логин и пароль, данные из полей передаются на сервер в формате json, и у меня проблема в том что я при отправке на сервер получаю ошибку которая состоит в том что данные в поле логин на данный момент отправляются в int и у меня не получается перевести эти данные из формата string в int:

```
Integer id = Integer.valueOf((mEmailView.getText().toString().trim()));
String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString().trim();
```

и у меня постоянно слетает приложение так как ошибка в этом поле при переводе из одного формата в другой, и поэтому у меня слетает приложение, я вроде посмотрел должно нормально переводить но почему-то оно не работает не правильно. Ошибка:

```
 --------- beginning of crash
07-11 02:30:18.411 6910-6910/com.example.developer_4.test_log E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.developer_4.test_log, PID: 6910
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "jdnjsnj"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:521)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:611)
        at com.example.developer_4.test_log.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:105)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)


    --------- beginning of system
```

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой или знает как мне помочь то буду очень благодарен.

Comment: stacktrace где?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.NumberFormatException` говорит об ошибке парсинга числа из строки. Строка, которую вы передали — `jdnjsnj`.

А вот где вы это делаете:

```
Integer id = Integer.valueOf((mEmailView.getText().toString().trim()));
```

Значит, в ваш `mEmailView` вводятся не только цифры.

Либо [запретите ввод любых символов кроме цифр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/728138/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-edittext-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0) в ваше поле для ввода, либо добавьте ручную валидацию перед парсингом.

---

Заметил ещё одну ошибку в вашем коде:

Вы используете `@POST("/{login}/{password}")`, но при этом не пишете `@Path("login")` и `@Path("password")`. Почитайте примеры: http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Comment: а как сделать запрет на ввод  символов кроме цифр?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko дополнил ответ.

Comment: да кстати я вот ввожу только цифры в edittext только цифры символов я вообще не ввожу и у меня все-равно такая проблема, то есть все-таки нужно вставлять этот запрет или проблема все-таки в чем-то другом???

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko значит у вас уже другая проблема. В вашем вопросе была описана проблема, вы привели стактрейс ошибки — если вы бы добавили в поле для ввода только цифры, а приложение всё равно падает, значит появляется уже другая ошибка. Я дал исчерпывающий ответ на текущий вопрос, проверьте стактрейс и можете задать отдельный вопрос, если ошибка другая.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko дополнил ответ, увидел ещё одну ошибку у вас.

Comment: спасибо, в следующий раз буду задавать вопросы более точно))

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko если ответ решает проблему, указанную в вопросе, и удовлетворяет вас — отметьте его как верный с помощью галочки, которая находится чуть левее самого ответа.